# How to take user input and use it to print parts of an array?

Tags: arrays, c

I have an array which is the months of the year:

```
const char *months[12] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novemeber", "December" };
```

I want to take user input using scanf and then print the corresponding month to the number the user enters.

Comment: What's the problem ? can you show us your actual code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: something like `int m; scanf("%d", &m); printf("%s\n", months[m]);`? Your C learning material should cover this.

Comment: I know how to take the input from the user and store it in an int, but I don't know how to match the entered number to the position of the element. Thanks

Comment: @j_tulloch157 then read the chapter dealing with arrays in your C learning maertial

Comment: Thank you Jabberwocky, your response has solved my problem. :)

Comment: You know how to declare a character pointer array but not how to read an integer with scanf and access an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the user input with scanf saving it in an int variable. Then just use square brackets to access that position and print it.
Code would be

```
    int a;
    const char *months[12] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novemeber", "December" }; 
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%s",months[a]);
```

Comment: You should check the value of `a` first

Comment: Yeah obviously you should check if a is in range, and also maybe print a message to let the user know what he's doing and so on ... I just wrote the basis :)

Comment: Giving the answer might not be very helpfull.

Comment: @mmeisson i think "use square brackets to access that position in array" is enough. The snippet I add is just to make it clearer

Comment: Esotopo21, If the user enter 1, I'd expect `"January"`, not `"February"`.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @chux You not me :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't use scanf for reading numbers. It has poor end of line handling.
NOTE: Research on tutorialspoint - [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) [sscanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) [specifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c) [printf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm)

Use fgets to read in the stdin (user input) as a string. Convert it to an integer with sscanf.

```
char input[20];
int month_num;

printf("enter number and press ENTER: ");
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
sscanf(input,"%d",&month_num);
```

Then, print out the index of the month array.

```
printf("%s \n", months[month_num]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is week 3 of C for me, I have a lot to learn! I will make sure to read through the links.

Comment: @j_tulloch157 - happy to help.